# How to Calculate the Average and Standard Deviation of Two Ranges

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the average and standard deviation of two ranges within a data frame and I am not able to come up with a solution.

I am able to calculate the average of two different ranges and then average both of them out but that doesn't give the correct value mathematically. As show in the example

E.g: For X6: The average of all months excluding June is 12. But when I take two averages of two different range instead of one average, this gives out a wrong value. But in excel we set the correct value 12 as expected since the average function has the ability to take two rows.

Can anyone let me know if this is possible, this is possible in excel but I am not sure if this is possible in R.

The Data Frame I am working with is :

```
structure(list(Type = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B"), `Row Labels` = c("X6", 
"X7", "X8", "X9", "X11", "X12"), `2023-03-01` = c(14, 50, 75, 
100, 25, 50), `2023-04-01` = c(16, 50, 75, 100, 25, 50), `2023-05-01` = c(14, 
50, 75, 100, 50, 100), `2023-06-01` = c(11, 50, 75, 100, 75, 
150), `2023-07-01` = c(9, 50, 75, 100, 125, 250), `2023-08-01` = c(9, 
50, 75, 100, 200, 400), `2023-09-01` = c(11, 50, 75, 100, 325, 
650), `2023-10-01` = c(11, 50, 75, 100, 525, 1050), Avg = c(12, 
50, 75, 100, 182.142857142857, 364.285714285714), `Std Dev` = c(2.70801280154532, 
0, 0, 0, 186.365616080711, 372.731232161421), X1 = c(14.6666666666667, 
50, 75, 100, 33.3333333333333, 66.6666666666667), X2 = c(10, 
50, 75, 100, 293.75, 587.5), X3 = c(12.3333333333333, 50, 75, 
100, 163.541666666667, 327.083333333333)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]
[image]

The code I wrote for this is:

```
library(readxl)

Book1 <- read_excel("C:/X/X/X- X/X/Book1.xlsx",sheet = "Sheet4")
dput(Book1)

Book1$X1 <- rowMeans(Book1[,3:5])
Book1$X2 <- rowMeans(Book1[,7:10])
Book1$X3 <- (Book1$X1+Book1$X2)/2

dput(Book1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just index columns by `c(3:5, 7:10)`:

```
Book1$M <- rowMeans(Book1[, c(3:5, 7:10)])
Book1$SD <- apply(Book1[, c(3:5, 7:10)], 1, sd)

Book1[, c(1,2,16,17)]
# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   Type  `Row Labels`     M     SD
#   <chr> <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 A     X6             12    2.71
# 2 B     X7             50    0   
# 3 C     X8             75    0   
# 4 C     X9            100    0   
# 5 A     X11           182. 186.  
# 6 B     X12           364. 373.
```